# How to send json back to angular using electron-json-storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, electron

I'm using [electron-json-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-json-storage) to read/write json files and [ngElectron](https://github.com/develephant/ngElectron) in an electron app. The guide for electron-json-storage reads this:

```
storage.get('foobar', function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
});
```

When calling that function from angular using ngElectron, it prints ok in console, but how can I get the object to store it in a scope and use it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found out how to do it

in electron part I had to return a promise

```
var deferred = q.defer();
storage.get('local Storage', function (error, data) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
    deferred.reject({'status': 500, 'result': {}, 'error': error});
  }
    deferred.resolve({'status': 200, 'result': data});
  });
return deferred.promise;
```

in angular part

```
ls.get('local Storage').then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```